# Measure size of object by depth stereo camera with DepthAI

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, luxonis

With stereo depth camera you can estimate distance from fixed object. Is it possible measure precise object size using openCV or similar ? Is there any deep-learning application that draws 3D box around the recognized object ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First, I have a Luxonis DepthAI camera which can be programmed by DepthAI API, openCV, python and OpenVINO. I want to develop a python program that acquire object image from fixed position and estimate object size. Hieght of object can be estimated by stereo camera given the distance between camera and support surface of the object. L and W I guess could be estimated by measuring bounding box. I don't know how to do this calculation. With H, L, W than I assume a 3D bounding box can be drawn by OpenCV